# SoundCloud iframe of sets stays 200px

Tags: iframe, wordpress, height, soundcloud

For some reason since this week all my SoundCloud sets are only 200px high thereby cropping the player. I am using the official WordPress plugin.

I have disabled all my plugins, emptied and disabled Cloudeflare and tried temporarily deactivating all my custom code. I have also tried multiple variables in the setting menu of the plugin and tried to change the height using `iframe[Attributes Style] {height: 600px !important;}`

Example: http://fastforwardandrewind.com/10840/dream-this-isnt-house-ep/
It should look like this: http://soundcloud.com/owslaofficial/sets/dream-this-isnt-house-ep/

Does anybody know what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Thanks,
Ricardo

Comment: Hey Ricardo, we'll look into it and hopefully get a fix for you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific height set in your plugin settings? Also, can you give an example of a shortcode you are using?

As a stopgap solution, you can revert to an older [SoundCloud plugin version (2.0)](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/soundcloud-shortcode.2.0.zip).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The older version of the plugin fixed the problem for me, so this problem definitely lies somewhere in the newest update of the plugin. Thanks for getting my site back on track!